# Дать возможность клиенту выбрать большее кол-во товаров для заказа еды

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Привет всем.

Столкнулся с проблемой: если 1 - это Гамбургер, 2 - это кола, 
то когда клиент заказывает гамбургер и колу, мне придется создавать еще одну запись отдельно для колы и отдельно для гамбургера.

Как это нивелировать, что бы я мог поместить туда и гамбургер и колу?

```
Таблица продуктов                      Таблица заказов
num_prod   name_prod                 num_zakaz num_prod      data_zakaz
--------  ----------                 --------- ---------      ----------
1          Gamburger                    102       1            sysdate     
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2          Cola                         103     тут клиент     sysdate
                                               хочет и гамб.
                                                  и колу
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать три таблицы:

1. "Продукты", колонки: ID продукта, название продукта
2. "Заказы", колонки: ID заказа, дата заказа
3. связующая таблица, колонки: ID записи, ID заказа, ID продукта

В связующей таблице для каждого заказа будет столько строчек, сколько продуктов в заказе. Например, для вашего случая связующая таблица будет выглядеть так:

```
id    id_заказа   id_продукта
-----------------------------
1     102         1
2     103         1
3     103         2
```

Рекомендую погуглить "нормализация базы данных". Есть определённые правила, соблюдение которых поможет проектировать вам более ясные и удобные базы и избежать множество граблей.